# Magento 2 category page error after custom attribute added

Tags: magento2, category, attributes

I've created a new attribute which works fine on the product page but seems to break the category page. I get the following error and I'm not sure how to fix it.

> Notice: Undefined variable: result in
>   /var/www/html/magento/vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Listing/Configurable.php
>   on line 48

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

list.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
 */
?>
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */      echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
<?php
if ($block->getMode() == 'grid') {
    $viewMode = 'grid';
    $image = 'category_page_grid';
    $showDescription = false;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
} else {
    $viewMode = 'list';
    $image = 'category_page_list';
    $showDescription = true;
    $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::FULL_VIEW;
}
/**
 * Position for actions regarding image size changing in vde if needed
 */
$pos = $block->getPositioned();
?>
<div class="products wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $viewMode; ?>">
    <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <?php /** @var $_product \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product */ ?>
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="item product product-item">' : '</li><li class="item product product-item">' ?>
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">
                <?php
                $productImage = $block->getImage($_product, $image);
                if ($pos != null) {
                    $position = ' style="left:' . $productImage->getWidth() . 'px;'
                        . 'top:' . $productImage->getHeight() . 'px;"';
                }
                ?>
                <?php // Product Image ?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                    <?php echo $productImage->toHtml(); ?>
                </a>
                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                    <?php
                        $_productNameStripped = $block->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                    ?>
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link"
                           href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                    <!--<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>-->
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
                    <!--<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>-->

                    <div class="product-item-inner">
                        <div class="product actions product-item-actions"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-actions') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                            <!-- <div class="actions-primary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-primary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
                                    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
                                        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
                                        <button type="submit"
                                                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                        </button>
                                    </form>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?php if ($_product->getIsSalable()): ?>
                                        <div class="stock available"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('In stock') ?></span></div>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span></div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div> -->
                            <!-- <div data-role="add-to-links" class="actions-secondary"<?php echo strpos($pos, $viewMode . '-secondary') ? $position : ''; ?>>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()): ?>
                                    <a href="#"
                                       class="action towishlist"
                                       title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                       aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Wish List')); ?>"
                                       data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_product); ?>'
                                       data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                       role="button">
                                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                    </a>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php
                                $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare');
                                ?>
                                <a href="#"
                                   class="action tocompare"
                                   title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                   aria-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Compare')); ?>"
                                   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_product); ?>'
                                   role="button">
                                    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </div> -->
                        </div>
                        <?php if ($showDescription):?>
                            <div class="product description product-item-description">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_productNameStripped ?>"
                                   class="action more"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Learn More') ?></a>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
<?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled()) : ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
            "catalogAddToCart": {}
        }
    }
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**EDIT**

filter.phtml

```
            <ol class="items">
                <?php foreach ($filterItems as $filterItem): ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() > 0): ?>
                            <a href="<?php echo $block->escapeUrl($filterItem->getUrl()) ?>">
                                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                                <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                                    <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
                                        <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?> <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>

                        <?php else:?>
                            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getLabel() ?>
                            <?php if ($this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data')->shouldDisplayProductCountOnLayer()): ?>
                                <span class="count"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $filterItem->getCount()?><span class="filter-count-label">
                                    <?php if ($filterItem->getCount() == 1):?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('item')?><?php else:?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('items') ?><?php endif;?></span></span>

                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </ol>
```

Comment: Have you made any changes in list file

Comment: Please add more code lines, seem that you have customized the category page.

Comment: added list.phtml does this help?

Comment: You have customized the layer filter?

Comment: I've added the filter.phtml file